# Remove duplicates from array of strings in C

Tags: c, string, duplicates

I have an array of strings in C. The string length is around 3000 characters each. I thought to hash them for faster search results and preferred Perfect hashing. The problem is, perfect hash needs unique strings from data set to create hash function where as my data set has inevitable duplicates.

So now, I need a very fast way of removing duplicates from array of strings in C.
Kindly suggest the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Most likely the fastest way is to go through all strings in a loop, after your array is complete.

Comment: The idea of a hash is good, but you must find a way to deal with hash  collision, where two different strings share the same hash.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the array? If not,you can sort the array and remove adjacent duplicates.

Comment: I dont need to preserve the order. I will sort and remove duplicates.

Comment: >>> set(('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'))          
Result: a set object containing ['a', 'c', 'b']

Answer (score 1):

My first thought, without researching, was to potentially create some kind of basic hash for each string and only check the complete strings for equality if the hashes match. This should allow for speeding up the algorithm slightly, at a small cost to how straightforward the whole algorithm is. There should be a better solution than this, but it should help in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

These are the data structures which can help

### array

Add each item to an array. `qsort` the result.
Output the result but not if the previous string was a duplicate. Unix `sort | uniq`

### binary tree

Hold the strings in a binary tree. [Wikipedia binary tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).  As each string is added, then search the tree.  Add the string if it is not there.

### hash table

Use a hash of string to keep a hash table. Collisions are checked by strcmp, and duplicates not added.

### trie

[Wikipedia trie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  The trie stores the common prefix.  This would automatically 'lose' duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Removes duplicate strings from the array and shifts items left.
 * Returns the number of items in the modified array.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * n_items   - number of items in the array.
 * arr       - an array of strings with possible duplicates.
 */
int remove_dups(int n_items, char *arr[])
{
    int i, j = 1, k = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n_items; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1, k = j; j < n_items; j++)
        {
            /* If strings don't match... */
            if (strcmp(arr[i], arr[j])) 
            {
                arr[k] = arr[j];
                k++;
            }
        }
        n_items -= j - k;
    }
    return n_items;
}
```